# Comparator aware `flat_set` implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, stl

I am currently implementing a *flat_map* like container in C++, and had problems with the comparator used. Thus, I reduced it to the bare minimum which I will present here. (In particular, my code here implements a *set* instead of a map).

```cpp
template< typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T> >
class flat_set : private Compare {
public:
   flat_set() = default;
   flat_set( std::initializer_list<T> && init, const Compare & compare_ = Compare() ) 
      : Compare(compare_), values{init}
   {}

   template< typename V >
   [[nodiscard]] bool contains( const V & value ) const noexcept {
      auto it = std::lower_bound( values.begin(), values.end(), value, value_comp_ref() );
      return it != values.end() && eq( value, *it );
   }
   
   [[nodiscard]]       Compare   value_comp()     const   noexcept { return *this; }  // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-slicing)
   [[nodiscard]] const Compare & value_comp_ref() const & noexcept { return *this; }  // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-slicing)
   [[nodiscard]]       Compare & value_comp_ref()       & noexcept { return *this; }  // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-slicing)
   
private:
   template< typename Lhs, typename Rhs >
   [[nodiscard]] bool lt( const Lhs & lhs, const Rhs & rhs ) const noexcept {  // less than
      return Compare::operator()( lhs, rhs );
   }
   template< typename Lhs, typename Rhs >
   [[nodiscard]] bool eq( const Lhs & lhs, const Rhs & rhs ) const noexcept {  // equivalent
      return (!lt( lhs, rhs )) && (!lt( rhs, lhs ));
   }
   
   std::vector< T > values;
};
```

and some test code:

```cpp
int main() {
   flat_set< S, SComp > fs{S{3},S{2},S{1}};
   std::cout << fs.contains( S{2} );
   std::cout << fs.contains( 4 );
   
   auto v2 = fs.value_comp();
   std::cout << v2( S{3}, 2 );    

   auto & v5 = fs.value_comp_ref();
   std::cout << v5( S{3}, 2 );
   auto & vtmp = flat_set< S, SComp >{S{4},S{3},S{2},S{1}}.value_comp_ref();
   std::cout << flat_set< S, SComp >{S{3},S{2},S{1}}.contains(2);
}
```

My questions are:

- Do I handle the comparator in a good way. In particular

  - I added the function `value_comp_ref` because I fear that, when I pass `value_comp()` to `std::lower_bound` I get unnecessary copies. Would this be true?
  - My workaround via `value_comp_ref` to pass the comparator to `std::lower_bound` actually seems very strange to me, but it was the easiest I could come up with. Which other solutions I could do here?
- Are my `noexcept` specifiers correct? Are the `[[...]]` tags ok?
- Is there a more concise way to implement my functions `lt` and `eq`?

I do not wish to get feedback onto

- the missing `is_transparent` tests
- Missing allocator support

Comment: I’m unclear what the goal of this is. What was your reason not to use the second template parameter of `std::set`?

Comment: What do you mean? I cant use `std::set` at all in my flat_map implemention (In particular, I even do not use `std::vector` there because I need it on Cuda).

Comment: I’m a bit confused about what kind of project this is and therefore what feedack you’re looking for. The title says this is a comparator-aware `std::set`, and it has the tag `reinventing-the-wheel`, but `std::set` is already comparator-aware.

Comment: Your latest comment also makes me wonder whether a `std::vector` overloaded with a different allocator could not be used for CUDA. If it can, that’s almost certainly the most practical solution.

Comment: 1) There is some strange misunderstanding here. I am *reinventing-the-wheel*, and therefor I am obviously do *NOT* want to use `std::set` in my code, because I want to *reinvent* it. 2) Regarding `std::vector`: Cuda has no `std::` at all. In particular I cannot use a different allocator, because there even isnt a `std::vector`. 3) My question is: Is the comparator stuff implemented correctly.

Comment: My gut feeling here is that you may have an XY problem. I don’t know the constraints on your project, but it seems plausible to me that the STL containers would be interoperable with CUDA if you compile your `.cpp` separately from your `.cu`, specialize the templates properly, and link them together.

Comment: 1) Cuda has nothing (except for some very basic stuff like `std::move`) in namespace `std`. Thus, there is *no* way to use `std::` stuff in `__device__` code. 2) Furthermore, there is no `flat_map` in C++ (cuda currently supports C++14, partly C++17), and since we are working in cuda, I have to implement it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't inherit from `Compare`

Your `flat_set` does not have an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) with `Compare`. Also, who knows what kind of type a caller will pass to `flat_set`? It might cause problems if you don't have control over it. So it is much better to have it as a `private` member variable.

If you are worried about it potentially taking up space, consider using C++20's [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address).

This also avoids needing the `value_comp()` functions to cast `*this` into a `Compare`.

## Make use of `std::binary_search()`

`std::lower_bound()` does more work than necessary; you don't care that you get a reference to the lowest item with the given value, you only want to know whether it exists. It is annoying to use here, because the item returned might not even have the same value, so you need an extra check. Since you sorted the vector, [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) is doing exactly what you want: it just returns a `bool` indicating whether the given value was found.

As a bonus, there is no need at all any more for `lt()` and `eq()`.

## What about the allocator?

> I do not wish to get feedback onto
>
> - Missing allocator support

I am going to give that feedback anyway, since it might be useful for someone else.

Especially as you are using a flat set, I would think that the programmer is looking to optimize things as much as possible, in which case they might be thinking of using a custom allocator as well. So just like `std::set`, it might be nice to have a configurable allocator, which is passed to the `std::vector` used to store the elements.

## Incorrect use of `noexcept`

A good way to check if you can make a function `noexcept` is to check if all the functions you are calling inside it are also `noexcept`. If not, it's probably a bad idea to make your function `noexcept`. Since `std::lower_bound()` is not `noexcept`, `contains()` should not be `noexcept`.

Also consider that someone might pass a `Compare` function that is not `noexcept`, and that since `contains()` is templated, there might be an implicit cast from `V` to `T` when passing `value` to the comparator, which in turn might also throw.

On the other hand, you could might make the default constructor `noexcept`, depending on whether `Allocator()` and `Compare()` are noexcept, as then the [default constructor of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is `noexcept` as well, at least since C++17, and you are also constructing a new `Compare` (regardless of whether you inherited from it or whether it's a member value).

## You can make things `constexpr` in C++20

Since C++20, a lot of member functions of `std::vector`, including many of the constructors, are `constexpr`. Also, `std::binary_search()` is `constexpr` since C++20. So if you raise the minimum supported version of C++ for your code, you could make most of the API of `flat_set` `constexpr` as well.

## Example code

Here is an example of your code with the above suggestions added, including the ones that only apply if C++20 can be used, although they can easily be removed if necessary.

```
template< typename T,
          typename Compare = std::less<T>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class flat_set {
public:
   constexpr flat_set() noexcept(noexcept(Allocator()) && noexcept(Compare()))
                        = default;
   constexpr flat_set( std::initializer_list<T> && init,
                       const Compare & compare_ = Compare(),
                       const Allocator& allocator = Allocator() ) 
      : compare(compare_), values{init, allocator}
   {}

   template< typename V >
   [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool contains( const V & value ) const {
      return std::binary_search( values.begin(), values.end(), value, compare );
   }
      
private:
   [[no_unique_address]] Compare compare{};
   std::vector< T, Allocator > values;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your review. There are some good points. But you may fix an error: I use *private* inheritance, which does not mean *is-a* but *is-implemented-in-terms-of*.

Comment: I don't think I made an error. While private inheritance can indeed be seen as an is-implemented-in-terms-of relationship, it still often is a bad idea if there is not a strong is-a relationship as well. Privately inheriting from a `std::vector` might have been better: your flat set is implemented as a vector, with some set-like public functions added.

Comment: Another remark to the allocator support. This I implemented by templatizing the underlying container.

Comment: That's probably a good way to do it. Consider creating a new question on Code Review with the full implementation of your `class flat_set`.